# I2C keeps giving me 0 when I try to read data from my RTC

Tags: microcontroller, hardware, clock, i2c, pic

I am currently trying to make my PIC16F1789 communicate with my RTC module (PCF8523T). I have spent multiple hours searching for errors, but I can't find any. I have verified that the RTC module is working as intended. PCF8523_Read should be returning the actual value, but it only returns 0. I cannot for the life of me figure out why this happens.

main.c

```
#include <xc.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "LCD.h"
#include "I2C.h"
#include "PCF8523.h"
#define _XTAL_FREQ  20000000

#pragma config FOSC = HS        // Oscillator Selection bits (HS oscillator)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF       // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = ON       // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT enabled)
#pragma config BOREN = OFF      // Brown-out Reset Enable bit (BOR disabled)
#pragma config LVP = OFF        // Low-Voltage (Single-Supply) In-Circuit Serial Programming Enable bit (RB3 is digital I/O, HV on MCLR must be used for programming)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data EEPROM Memory Code Protection bit (Data EEPROM code protection off)
#pragma config WRT = OFF        // Flash Program Memory Write Enable bits (Write protection off; all program memory may be written to by EECON control)
#pragma config CP = OFF         // Flash Program Memory Code Protection bit (Code protection off)

void __interrupt() InterruptServiceRoutine()
{
    if(PIR1bits.RCIF && PIE1bits.RCIE)
    {
        PIR1bits.RCIF = 0;
    }
}

void delay_s(unsigned int numseconds) 
{
    do 
    {
        __delay_ms(1000);
    } while (--numseconds != 0);
}

void main(void) {
    // -- Pin I/O
    TRISB0 = 1; // Pin B0 is INPUT  (LCD toggle button)
    TRISB1 = 0; // Pin B1 is OUTPUT (Blue LED; -> Pump running / Valve Open indicator) (GOES INTO J2)
    TRISB2 = 0; // Pin B2 is OUTPUT (Red LED;  -> Low water level indicator / No water at valve) (GOES INTO J2)
    TRISB4 = 0; // Pin B4 is OUTPUT (Valve) (GOES INTO J1)
    TRISC5 = 0; // Pin C5 is OUTPUT (LCD ON/OFF)
    
    // -- Variables
    bool Lcd_Enabled = true;    // Currently alway true (IGNORE)
    unsigned char msg[] = "Hochbeet (--/--)";
    unsigned char Time[] = "UHRZEIT: --:--";
    unsigned char Min,Hour,Day,Month;
    
    unsigned char SetHour = 9;
    unsigned char SetMin = 15;  // Time when the automatic watering system triggers.
    
    RC5 = 0;
    RB2 = 0;
    
    I2C_Init();
    
    PCF8523_Init();
    Lcd_Init();
    Lcd_Write_Text(msg);
    Lcd_Cmd(LCD_SECOND_ROW);
    Lcd_Write_Text(Time);
    
    while (1) 
    {
        Min = PCF8523_Read(MINUTES);    // These always return 0????
        Hour = PCF8523_Read(HOURS);
        Day = PCF8523_Read(DAYS);
        Month = PCF8523_Read(MONTHS);
        
        if (Lcd_Enabled == true) 
        {
            Lcd_Cmd(LCD_FIRST_ROW + 10);
            Lcd_Write(BCD2UpperCh(Day));
            Lcd_Write(BCD2LowerCh(Day));
            Lcd_Write('/');
            Lcd_Write(BCD2UpperCh(Month));
            Lcd_Write(BCD2LowerCh(Month));
            Lcd_Write(')');
            
            Lcd_Cmd(LCD_SECOND_ROW + 9);
            Lcd_Write(BCD2UpperCh(Hour));
            Lcd_Write(BCD2LowerCh(Hour));
            Lcd_Write(':');
            Lcd_Write(BCD2UpperCh(Min));
            Lcd_Write(BCD2LowerCh(Min));
        }
        
        if(RB0) 
        {
            if (Lcd_Enabled == false) {
                Lcd_Enabled = true;
                RC5 = 1;
                Lcd_Init();
                Lcd_Write(msg);
                Lcd_Cmd(LCD_SECOND_ROW);
                Lcd_Write(Time);
            }
        }
        else if (Hour == SetHour && Min == SetMin) 
        {
            RB4 = 1;
            RB1 = 1;
            if (Lcd_Enabled == true) 
            {
                Lcd_Cmd(LCD_SECOND_ROW);
                Lcd_Write("Wasser ist an!");
            }
            delay_s(60); // Turn on water for 1 minute
            RB4 = 0;
            RB1 = 0;
            if (Lcd_Enabled == true) 
            {
                Lcd_Cmd(LCD_SECOND_ROW);
                Lcd_Write(Time);
            }
            delay_s(3);
        }
        else 
        {
            __delay_ms(500);
            
        }
    }
}
```

PCF8523.h

```
#ifndef PC8523_H
#define PC8523_H

#define     PC8523_ADDRESS  0xD0
#define     CONTROL_1       0x00
#define     CONTROL_2       0x01
#define     CONTROL_3       0x02
#define     SECONDS         0x03    // UNUSED
#define     MINUTES         0x04
#define     HOURS           0x05
#define     DAYS            0x06
#define     WEEKDAYS        0x07
#define     MONTHS          0x08
#define     YEARS           0x09    // UNUSED
#define     MINUTE_ALARM    0x0A
#define     HOUR_ALARM      0x0B
#define     DAY_ALARAM      0x0C
#define     WEEKDAY_ALARM   0x0D
#define     OFFSET          0x0E
#define     TMR_CLKOUT_CTRL 0x0F
#define     TMR_A_FREQ_CTRL 0x10
#define     TMR_A_REG       0x11
#define     TMR_B_FREQ_CTRL 0x12
#define     TMR_B_REG       0x13

void PCF8523_Init(void);
void PCF8523_SetTimeDate(unsigned char hours,unsigned char minutes,unsigned char seconds,unsigned char day,unsigned char month,unsigned char year);
void PCF8523_SetTime(unsigned char hours,unsigned char minutes,unsigned char seconds);
void PCF8523_SetDate(unsigned char day,unsigned char month,unsigned char years);
unsigned char PCF8523_Read(unsigned char Address);
unsigned char BCD2UpperCh(unsigned char bcd);
unsigned char BCD2LowerCh(unsigned char bcd);

#endif  /* PC8523_H */
```

PCF8523.c

```
#include <xc.h>
#include "PCF8523.h"
#include "I2C.h"

void PCF8523_Init(void)
{
    I2C_Init();
}
void PCF8523_SetTimeDate(unsigned char hours,unsigned char minutes,unsigned char seconds,unsigned char day,unsigned char month,unsigned char year)
{
    PCF8523_SetTime(hours,minutes,seconds);
    PCF8523_SetDate(day,month,year);
}
void PCF8523_SetTime(unsigned char hours,unsigned char minutes,unsigned char seconds)
{
    I2C_Start();
    I2C_Send(PC8523_ADDRESS);
    I2C_Send(SECONDS);
    I2C_Send(seconds);
    I2C_Send(minutes);
    I2C_Send(hours);
    I2C_Stop();
}
void PCF8523_SetDate(unsigned char day,unsigned char month,unsigned char years)
{
    I2C_Start();
    I2C_Send(PC8523_ADDRESS);
    I2C_Send(DAYS);
    I2C_Send(day);
    I2C_Send(0x00);
    I2C_Send(month);
    I2C_Send(years);
    I2C_Stop();
}
unsigned char PCF8523_Read(unsigned char Address)
{
    unsigned char temp;
    I2C_Start();
    I2C_Send(PC8523_ADDRESS);
    I2C_Send(Address);
    I2C_Restart();
    I2C_Send(PC8523_ADDRESS+1);
    temp = I2C_Read();
    I2C_Stop();
    return temp;
}
unsigned char BCD2UpperCh(unsigned char bcd)
{
    unsigned char temp;
    temp = bcd >> 4;
    temp = temp | 0x30;
    return(temp);
}
unsigned char BCD2LowerCh(unsigned char bcd)
{
    unsigned char temp;
    temp = bcd & 0x0F; //Making the Upper 4-bits
    temp = temp | 0x30;
    return(temp);
}
```

I2C.h

```
#ifndef I2C_H
#define I2C_H

#define i2c_init        I2C_Init
#define I2C_init        I2C_Init
#define I2c_init        I2C_Init
#define i2c_init        I2C_Init

#define I2c_Start       I2C_Start
#define I2C_start       I2C_Start
#define I2c_start       I2C_Start
#define i2c_start       I2C_Start

#define I2c_Restart     I2C_Restart
#define I2C_restart     I2C_Restart
#define I2c_restart     I2C_Restart
#define i2c_restart     I2C_Restart

#define I2c_Stop        I2C_Stop
#define I2C_stop        I2C_Stop
#define I2c_stop        I2C_Stop
#define i2c_stop        I2C_Stop

#define I2c_Wait        I2C_Wait
#define I2C_wait        I2C_Wait
#define I2c_wait        I2C_Wait
#define i2c_wait        I2C_Wait

#define I2c_Send        I2C_Send
#define I2C_send        I2C_Send
#define I2c_send        I2C_Send
#define i2c_send        I2C_Send

#define I2c_Read        I2C_Read
#define I2C_read        I2C_Read
#define I2c_read        I2C_Read
#define i2c_read        I2C_Read

void I2C_Init(void);
void I2C_Start(void);
void I2C_Restart(void);
void I2C_Stop(void);
void I2C_Wait(void);
void I2C_Send(unsigned char data);
unsigned char I2C_Read(void);


#endif  /* I2C_H */
```

I2C.c

```
#include "I2C.h"
#include <xc.h>

void I2C_Init(void)
{
    TRISCbits.TRISC3 = 1;
    TRISCbits.TRISC4 = 1;
    SSPSTAT |= 0x80; //Slew Rate Disabled
    SSPADD = 49;

    SSPCON = 0b00101000;            //Master mode
    SSPADD = 49;
    /*SSPEN = 1
    Enables the Serial Port and configures the SDA and SCL
    Pins as the Serial Pins
    SSPM3:SSPM0 --> 1000
    I2C Master Mode
    Clock = Fosc/4*(SSPADD+1)
    */
}
void I2C_Start(void)
{
    SEN = 1;
    //SSPCON2 bit 0
    while (SEN == 1)
        continue;
    //SEN =1 initiate the Start Condition on SDA and SCL Pins
    //Automatically Cleared by Hardwre
    // 0 for Idle State
}
void I2C_Restart(void)
{
    RSEN = 1;
    //SSPCON2 bit 0
    while (RSEN == 1)
        continue;
    //RSEN =1 initiate the Start Condition on SDA and SCL Pins
    //Automatically Cleared by Hardwre
    // 0 for Idle State
}
void I2C_Stop(void)
{
    PEN = 1;
    //SSPCON2 bit 0
    while (PEN == 1)
        continue;
    //PEN =1 initiate the Start Condition on SDA and SCL Pins
    //Automatically Cleared by Hardwre
    // 0 for Idle State
}
void I2C_Wait(void)
{
    while( R_nW == 1)
        continue;
    if(ACKSTAT == 1)
    {
        I2C_Stop();
    }
    //If ACKSTAT bit is 0 Acknowledgment Received Successfully
    //Otherwise Not
}
void I2C_Send(unsigned char data)
{
    SSPBUF = data;    /* Move data to SSPBUF */
    while(BF);       /* wait till complete data is sent from buffer */
    I2C_Wait();       /* wait for any pending transfer */
}
unsigned char I2C_Read(void)
{
    unsigned char temp;
    RCEN = 1;        /* Enable data reception */
    while(BF == 0)      /* wait for buffer full */
        continue;
    temp = SSPBUF;   /* Read serial buffer and store in temp register */
    I2C_Wait();       /* wait to check any pending transfer */
    ACKDT=1;                //send not acknowledge
    ACKEN=1;
    while(ACKEN == 1)
        continue;
    //I2C_Stop();
    return temp;
}
```

Circuit schematic
[image: Image of circuit's schematic]

Comment: Did you check 1) that you receive an ACK, and 2) that the clock actually runs? There is a `STOP` bit in register `Control_1`.

Comment: OT: Your header with all these `#define`s for typos of the functions is terrible. **You** specify the names of the functions, and all users have to write them correctly.